# Is there a machine learning algorithm that swaps out variables in a model?

Tags: machine-learning, r

Let's say that I have a model that uses three variables, and each of those three variables have different variants. For example, variable two could be species diversity, but there are different variants such as Shannon-Wiener, Simpson's, Inverse Simpson's, etc. Is there a machine learning algorithm (preferably in R) that could test different combinations of the variable variants?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and please let me know if you have any clarifying questions.

Comment: Do you mean training one model with Shannon, another with Simpson, and another with inverse Simpson?

Comment: Essentially! So, train one model with Shannon while keeping variable 1 and variable 3 constant, then train another with Simpson while keeping the other two constant, etc. Basically, an algorithm that will test every combination of variables and then return the model with the best training MSE. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is you want to find the best variant for each variable. This is similar to looking for the best parameter value for each parameter of a ML model. We can use parameter grid search for the later, so we can also use grid search for your purpose?

Pseudo code:

```
for variantA in [variantA1, variantA2, ... ] do
   for variantB in [variantB1, variantB2, ...] do
      model = modeltraining(variantA, variantB)
      score = modeleval(model)

   end for
end for
```

Then you compare scores to get the best combination of variants.

Comment: Thanks for your response! This may just be what I am looking for. So, to make sure, if I had three variables, it would look like this:
<br>
`for variantA in [variantA1, variantA2, ... ] do
   for variantB in [variantB1, variantB2, ...] do
     for variantC in [variantC1, variantC2, ...] do
       model = modeltraining(variantA, variantB, variantC)
       score = modeleval(model)

    end for
  end for
end for
`
<br>
Also, am I alright to assume that it is okay for the variables to have different number of variants? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Yes and yes! In this way you can try out all combinations of variants.